# js telegram bot. How to listen messages from my private channels and redirect to my channel

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Can you provide some info on how to access js telegram bot to all my messages (from private channels)? I use node telegram bot API and know how to redirect messages that the bot received directly but how can the bot listen to messages from my private channels? Help me please to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [TDLIB](https://github.com/tdlib/td) with [airgram](https://github.com/airgram/airgram).

You need to log into your TG account and then find and send the required information to your bots.

I have a small example https://github.com/ysset/telegram-api